# Is there a UX SE research portal like the one in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Do we have anything like the research portal on Stack Overflow for UXSE where they do annual surveys and release the [results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016)? I would love to see this done because it helps all of us to understand the nature of the industry as it changes and evolves.